# Invoke Outlook with Attachment in Silverlight 4

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

[image: Mail Without Attachemnt]

I would like to invoke Outlook with To,Subject,Attachments in silverlight Application.
Is that possible to invoke Outlook With attachment. Sending Attachment is mondatory in application.

I achive this using NavigateUri in HyperLink. 
Using the Following Code

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="Mail" Content="Ramakrishnan" NavigateUri="mailto:user@domain.com?subject=Mail With Attachment Testing"> 
                </HyperlinkButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Outlook, but only in OOB mode. Mike Taulty has a blogpost [Silverlight 4 – Grabbing Emails from the Outlook Inbox](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/12/23/silverlight-4-grabbing-emails-from-the-outlook-inbox.aspx). It can help you.

You need to use [AutomationFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.automation.automationfactory%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) so take a look to it as well.

Comment: I want to show Outlook window in browser Application, I dont want to use it in Out-of-Browser Application

Comment: You can't run Outlook from browser application, it is only possible for OOB applications. [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff457794(VS.95).aspx) describes the only way you can use Automation factory.

Comment: Here are links to other solutions which use wcf services to send email: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/137451/307278.aspx, http://www.silverlightnext.com/2010/06/send-email-from-silverlight-application.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will search for other solutions.

Comment: Funny, the valid question and the only answer addressing the actual question were the only two things that didn't got upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're after is sending emails from your silverlight application, you could look at implementing a solution using the [Exchange Web Services - Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx).

For my situation I made a ASP.NET WebService that handled all the Exchange Communication for my web page which meant that the web page remained slim. Using the EWS API you can easily read or create and send mail through exchange directly without having to deal with any Outlook interop mess.

For More info see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637749(v=exchg.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

What I did was make an Outlook Add-in that exposes a WCF Service and does the work.